# Syntax error for looping through a JSON file

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, api, loops

I'm trying to loop through this JSON file to figure out the country with the highest Total cases of COVID and then display the country for it. I'm not sure if this is the right approach or not. When debugging it, it says I have a syntax error on the line with my for loop?

```js
var requestOptions = {
  method: 'GET',
  redirect: 'follow'
};

fetch("https://api.covid19api.com/summary", requestOptions)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(result => {   
  let array = [result.Countries];
    let topCountry = "0";
    let max = 0;
    
    for (i = 0; i<(6); i++)
        {   
            if (array[i].Countries.TotalConfirmed > max)
                {
                    let topCountry = array[i].Countries.Country;
                    let max = array[i].Countries.TotalConfirmed;
                }
        }
    
    console.log(topCountry);
})

  .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
```

Answer (score 0):

You would want to define `topCountry` outside the loop, and compare each member of the array to that. Right now you're just comparing each member of the array to the one immediately after it (`i+1`), which doesn't make sense. And when `i` hits the last element of the array you'll get an error because `i+1` doesn't exist.

Comment: let array = [result.Countries];
    
    let topCountry = "0";
    let max = 0;
    
    for (int i = 0; i<(array.length); i++)
        {   
            if (array[i].Countries.TotalConfirmed > max)
                {
                    let topCountry = array[i].Countries.Country;
                    let max == array[i].Countries.TotalConfirmed
                }
        }
    
    
    console.log(topCountry)

Comment: like that? I create a new int value max, set it to 0, and then made the comparison with max instead, and everytime the new value from array was greater than max, it set it equal to max. It still says I have a syntax error on the line with the for loop?I changed the array.length - 1 to just array.length.

Comment: It looks like you have the concept correct. You have `max == array[i].Countries...` which should not have two equal signs, You want a single equal sign because you are re-assigning `max`. Other than that I don't see an error but it's hard to read code in comments like this. Ah. Sorry. You don't want to say `let max` within the loop. You already created `max` with the `let` outside the loop. So now you can just say `max=array[i].Countries.TotalConfirmed` without the `let`. Basically, you only use `let` or `var` the first time you name a variable. `let` makes it accessible only deeper brackets

Comment: I tried that but it still gives me a syntax error on the with if(array[i].TotalConfirmed > max)

Comment: Your error is probably because you are asking for something that does not exist. Your original code has array=[result.Countries] but then you are asking for array[0].Countries.TotalConfirmed. That would throw an error because if array[0].Countries (which it would be) then you're asking for a property called TotalConfirmed of undefined. Probably you meant to say array=result.Countries (without the brackets) and then look through the array[i].TotalConfirmed